# UITableView Header height got increased after changing system font size in iOS 8

Tags: ios, iphone, ios8

UITableView Header height got increased after changing system font size in iOS 8.
I have changed font size of iOS from setting menu.
When I saw my app's table view header it looks strange because height of header section got increased.
Is there any solution that my header section will not get affect by any system font change or any system activity.

Answer (score 0):

If your table header text fits on one line, choose a System font in the storyboard rather than one of the textStyles, and set the Autoshrink attribute to "fixed font size".
If this is a multiline header, use a custom view for the table header and embed UILabel with the text you need.